# How to implement a chrome extension popup desktop notification on fixed time interval

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want the chrome notify me on fixed time interval.
And I try to write this code, but only show one time.

```
var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
  'icon.png',
  'Free your eyes',
  'Please take a break'
);

function showNotify()
{
  notification.show();
  setTimeout("showNotify()", 2000);
}

showNotify();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) to run the code periodically.

Try something like this:

```
function show() {
  var notification = /* ... */
}
setInterval(show, 2000);
```

Comment: +1, better than `setTimeout` (which would need to be `setTimeout(showNotify, 2000);` in order to work) I would still pass in the function rather than the string.

Comment: Good point, edited to use the function name instead of the string.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the the main reason is I defined "notification" out of the showNotify function. Why?